# WebApp does not open on Tizen Emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I'm doing some test apps and trying to use the Tizen emulator to see them running. But, when I try to open my app, it doesn't.

At first, I was only getting a black screen when trying to open it, looking for some answers I saw some people suggesting to turn off the GPU on emulator, due to some issue with Intel or something. After do that, my app now does not open at all, it's like I've never clicked on it. Apperently, it builds and install properly, but it doesn't open.

I've tested the sdb -e dlog tool on my Windows 7 64 bits to try to understand what is happening and I've got this: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/18QFAcyEyyTNDu5n8ztceX4mbOZILDb0WIcuhUIXTnQ8/edit

Have someone seen something like this?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Could you please: 1) give more information about your app, at least if it's webapp or native app, what privileges it does; 2) post traceback with plaintext, I would recommend pastebin.com or similar service.

Comment: I'll get these informations and post them here.

Comment: My app is the HelloWorld web app example, available at: https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/dev-guide/2.2.1?redirect=https%3A//developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/cover_page.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tizen Web app does not open on Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618596/tizen-web-app-does-not-open-on-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the emulator really needs a machine with the necessary configuration, listed on: https://developer.tizen.org/downloads/sdk/installing-sdk/prerequisites-tizen-sdk 
Otherwise, webapps won't execute, only using the Web Emulator.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: that link is dead (404).  Got a better one?   Thanks!

Comment: Hey there. I'm really sorry for the late response. Maybe you have already found something, but these links can be helpful: https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio and https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/overview