# Tizen Web app does not open on Emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I'm trying to test my web app example, but, when I try to use it on Emulator nothing happens. The log shows this message every time I try to open my web app:

> 07-08 04:42:16.832 : INFO / Tizen::App ( 2258 : 2258 ) : static int
>   Tizen::App::_AppLifecycleManager::TerminateCallback(int, void*)(741) >
>   [E_OBJ_NOT_FOUND] Cannot acquire app from pid 2435.

I have the GPU option enabled, I'm using the 2.2.1 version of SDK on Windows 7 64bits and I enabled the Intel virtualization, but, it's not activated for my emulator.

Has anyone seen something like this? I can't test anything I do because my apps don't open, the native apps work properly, this problem is only with the web ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do this manually:

```
sdb install your_app.wgt
```

Then application icon will show on emulator and you can run the app. 
If you want to debug you can:

```
$sdb shell
$wrt-launcher -d -s your_app_id #id looks like eg.: xFS7seZxmM.CallLog 
port: 45849
result: launched
$exit
$sdb forward tcp:45849 tcp:45849
```

then in your localhost, on 45849 port you will have chrome debug console. You just have to open chrome and type url: localhost:45849 and you will get connected.

You can also try to install SDK 2.3 and check do you still have the same problem :)

Comment: In my case, there was no `wrt-launcher` on the device. I replaced it with `app_launcher` and it worked.